# How do I filter an array for unique objects that contain a certain value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filter

I have an array of Lines, which hold two vertices each (their start and end positions). When the user clicks on one of the vertices, it changes the value of Vertex.selected to true.

How do i filter this array to find all vertices that are selected:

```
0: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
1: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
2: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
3: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
4: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
5: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
6: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
7: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
8: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
9: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
10: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
11: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
12: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
13: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
14: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
15: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
16: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
17: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
18: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
19: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
20: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
21: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
22: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
23: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
24: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
25: Line {v1: Vertex, v2: Vertex}
```

I'm aware i could use `lines.filter(line => {})`, but not entirely sure how i extract unique vertices out of that filter for the properties inside the `line` object

Some of these vertices are the same, so obviously i would want to only filter for unique objects, rather than extracting the same object 5 times because its referenced 5 times.

Expected result:
`selectedVertices: [Vertex1, Vertex2, Vertex3]`

Result im trying to avoid:
`selectedVertices: [Vertex1, Vertex1, Vertex1, Vertex2, Vertex2, Vertex2, Vertex3, Vertex3, Vertex3, Vertex3]`

Comment: If you post with a tag like javascript, then add a [mcve] in JavaScript.

Comment: @zer00ne ive added the data to be filtered, and the expected result...what else could this possibly need to make it more clear?

Comment: Your objective is obvious, your effort to said objective is questionable. You post a question that concerns a problem ***in your code*** to which you have posted nothing of (in fact none of what you posted is JavaScript, it looks like what the console *might* log at best). Where is your code? You are asking someone to write your code not help on existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.filter` and then `array.reduce` function

Let me explain the reduce logic here, `acc` is initialized with an empty array, then for each element if it do not exist in the accumulator array the element is added to the accumulator array and the array is returned.

```
//sample data 
let arr1 = [{v1:{x:1,y:2,selected:true},v2:{x:2,y:3,selected:true}},
{v1:{x:1,y:2,selected:true},v2:{x:2,y:3,selected:true}},
{v1:{x:1,y:2,selected:true},v2:{x:2,y:3,selected:true}},
{v1:{x:3,y:4,selected:true},v2:{x:5,y:6,selected:false}},
{v1:{x:7,y:8,selected:false},v2:{x:2,y:3,selected:false}}];

var vartexArr = arr1.map(({v1, v2}) => [v1,v2])

let result = vartexArr.flat().filter(a => a.selected)
.reduce((acc, i) => { 
   if(!acc.find(({x,y}) => x === i.x && y === i.y)) 
       acc.push(i); 
   return acc; 
 }, []);

console.log(result);

//output
[{
  selected: true,
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}, {
  selected: true,
  x: 2,
  y: 3
}, {
  selected: true,
  x: 3,
  y: 4
}]
```

Comment: Its each individual vertex that is selected, not the entire line. So it needs to find the lines that have a selected vertex, then return which vertex is selected (or both if theyre both selected)

Comment: Can you provide sample data

Comment: In the original question, in the array of Lines, each Vertex object has a `selected` property, not the lines themselves.

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: If these vertices are meant to be compared with reference equality, this should be all it takes: `const selectedVertices = (lines) => new Set (lines. flatMap (line => [line .v1, line .v2]) .filter (v => v .selected))`

Comment: And if you want value equality, it could be something like: ``const selectedVertices = (lines) => Object.values (Object.fromEntries (lines .flatMap (({v1, v2}) => [v1, v2]) .filter (v => v.selected) .map (v => [`${v.x}|${v.y}`, v])))``.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by `isSelected` then get unique vertices:

```js
class Vertex {
    constructor(x, y, isSelected) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

class Line {
    constructor(v1, v2) {
        this.v1 = v1
        this.v2 = v2
    }
}

const lines = []
lines.push(new Line(new Vertex(1,1, true), new Vertex(2,1, true)))
lines.push(new Line(new Vertex(2,2, false), new Vertex(2,2, false)))
lines.push(new Line(new Vertex(3,1, true), new Vertex(1,1, true)))
lines.push(new Line(new Vertex(5,1, true), new Vertex(4,1, true)))

const selectedVertices = lines.flatMap(l => [l.v1, l.v2]).filter(v => v.isSelected).reduce(function(p, c) {
    let id = [c.x, c.y].join('|');
    if (p.temp.indexOf(id) === -1) {
        p.out.push(c);
        p.temp.push(id);
    }
    return p;
}, {temp: [], out: []}).out;

console.log(selectedVertices)
```